# PHP - get the name and value using foreach with array and stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [fullname] => sample student 
            [nickname] => sample 
            [photo_ids] => |453 
            [gender] => MALE 
            [nationality] => KOREAN 
        ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [fullname] => kim namkyun 
            [nickname] => tristan 
            [photo_ids] => |448 
            [gender] => MALE 
            [nationality] => KOREAN 
        ) 
)
```

I have this `array` and I wanted to get the name and value using `foreach` loop. BUT instead of getting the `fullname` and `sample student` for example. I get the `0` and the `1`, This is the result from `result()` return in `mysql`.

My attempt:

```
$data->param_students = $this->student_model->getItems(array('status'=>'APPROVED'),array('fullname','nickname','photo_ids','gender','nationality'));
foreach ($data->param_students as $key=>$value) {
    print_r($key);
}
```

Comment: _I get the 0 and the 1..._ Post the relevant part of the code

Comment: I edit my question sir

Comment: Now `print_r($value)`

Comment: the try `$value->fullname`

Comment: No I want the `$key` to be `fullname` and `$value` to be `sample student`

Comment: No you don't, that's impractical. You already know which keys you're looking for, so you just do `$value->fullname`.

Comment: It is okay I already got the answer thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In below snippet you will get key and value you are looking for.

```
foreach ($data->param_students as $value) {
   foreach($value as $k => $v){
       echo $k.' '.$v;
   }
}
```

Comment: This one is what I wanted Thanks man

Comment: You're welcome mate.

Answer (score 2):

```
$data->param_students = $this->student_model->getItems(array('status'=>'APPROVED'),array('fullname','nickname','photo_ids','gender','nationality'));
foreach ($data->param_students as $value) {
    print_r($value->fullname);
}
```